# Integrating my Program in Windows to replace thr default handler for that particular operation

Tags: windows, winapi, hook

I want to integrate my program in windows in such a way that, for exmaple, when the user presses ctrl + shift, or ctrl + v, or any other Key combo, my program should run. I've seen softwares like TeraCopy, which startup when Ctrl-V is pressed, and they handle the copy operation, instead of windows explorer (default handler).

I know it can be done using Windows SDK, but I'm not sure which API to use, or where to start. Can anyone give links/references/code to provide help?

Comment: I'm not narrowing the question to only the copy operation. It could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a keyboard hook, which can be implemented with `SetWindowsHookEx` and the `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` constant as the `idHook` parameter.

Then you can set up a callback function for whenever the key state changes. When a certain combination is detected (e.g. Ctrl and V are pressed at the same time, but no other modifier keys) then you can perform your action.

Keep in mind that certain programs will need to retain Ctrl+V for other purposes, so you will probably want to use `GetForegroundWindow` to detect if Windows Explorer is currently being targeted.

See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx

Comment: I'm aware of the Keyboard Hooks, but here I'm talking about something different. My program won't be running. It will run when a particular Key or Key combo is pressed.

Comment: You can't blindly hook stuff to nonexistant code. You'll need to have a resident process running in the background to handle the hook callback. From there you can pop up a window or use `CreateProcess` to fire up your process.

Comment: Also, I don't want the default operation being performed. In case of copy/paste, I don't want windows explorer to copy, my program should be doing it in its own way.

Comment: then how does TeraCopy work then? No process or service belonging to TeraCopy is running, still it pops up whenever I copy/paste a file..I wanna achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Just don't call `CallNextHookEx` within your hook callback, then return a nonzero value. This signifies that you've handled the event and it shouldn't be sent to the next hook or application message queue. From the MSDN documentation for KeyboardProc: "If the hook procedure processed the message, it may return a nonzero value to prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook chain or the target window procedure."

Comment: TeraCopy probably injects a DLL into explorer.exe, which then performs the hook. The DLL is just enabling a thread in a process. It's exactly the same deal for having your own process.

Comment: what if explorer processes the event before me? I mean, its not necessary that I get the event before explorer gets it. By the way, I'm wondering, a DLL which starts up my main process could be injected into explorer, which could prevent explorer from handling it somehow.

Comment: Hooks are executed in the reverse order they are registered in, then the message is passed to the target window. Windows Explorer does not use a hook to process Ctrl+V, it simply takes the key messages from its window message loop. If you register a hook, you'll always get called before Windows Explorer handles it. Furthermore, your hook will be called before any other hook that was created before yours. In terms of injecting DLLs, you should probably read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection